# Can VPN steal ssh password?

Tags: vpn, ssh

Is it possible leak ssh password while using vpn ?
I mean not ssh key but password!
Is it secure to connect via ssh(with plain password) while using vpn (like protonVPN or NordVPN).
Thanks.

Comment: Your VPN provider would not be able to steal your ssh password, because your ssh password is encrypted by the ssh tunnel.  It is analogous the fact that your VPN provider would not be able to steal the password that you use to login to your bank's web site, because your password is encrypted by the HTTPS tunnel to the site.

Answer (score 6):

In SSH, authentication happens once an encrypted tunnel is established. Thus, a passive attacker cannot see your password.

However, an active attacker could intercept the creation of a tunnel, pretending to be the server when communicating with the client, and pretending to be the client when communicating with the server. It would create two tunnels with itself in the middle position, forwarding and reading data as it passes through.

To prevent this classic attack, SSH uses two countermeasures:

1. The client saves the public key of the server. The client will display a warning when the key changes, because it could mean that the connection was intercepted (or that the server was reinstalled). Indeed, an attacker cannot spoof this public key. However, this does not protect the first connection, unless the client has a way to get the server's public key in advance through another secure channel.
2. The client can connect to the server using public key authentication. The client copy its public key onto the server in advance, then uses it to authenticate itself to the server. This way, the *server* can ensure that no attacker intercepted the creation of the tunnel. This also avoids the need to send a password. Like with the first method, the client needs to send its key using another secure channel. Sometimes, servers will have a secure web page to allow clients to upload their public SSH key for this purpose.

Most VPN providers like the ones you cite would not try an active attack, because it could be easily detected by someone paying attention. And if this became public, they would risk losing a lot of reputation and customers. But they risk far less using only passive attacks, because that cannot be detected unless they get caught using the information they spied on.

Comment: Regarding the warning: It's a very LOUD warning, the correct thing to do.
https://docs.acquia.com/cloud-platform/manage/ssh/rsa-key-warning/

Answer (score 0):

Even without a VPN it should be secure to authenticate to an SSH server with a password. SSH sets up an encrypted tunnel before the password is sent.

Using a VPN adds an additional layer of encryption making it that much more difficult to conduct an active MITM attack.

In both cases (VPN or no VPN), you are still at risk of falling victim to an active MITM attack if you don't verify the server's fingerprint before accepting it (i.e. The first time you connect to the SSH server).